# Swift получить список вложенных классов

Tags: swift, рефлексия, swift4

Каким образом в Swift получить список вложенных классов?

Другими словами: есть ли аналог Java метода `.class.getClasses()`

Comment: А не уточните, зачем это надо? Может, эту цель можно достичь иным способом.

Comment: Хотелось описать структуру БД struct классами. Написать функцию которая перебирала бы эти классы и на основании их полей создавала таблицы в MySQl. Надеюсь понятно описал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько мне известно решить Вашу задачу с помощью Swift 4.1 нельзя, потому что в данной версии языка Swift (как и в предыдущих) описание вложенного класса не принадлежит конкретному объекту, то есть по сути является статическим (и компилятор оповестит Вас о ненужности использования `static` в данном случае). Следовательно, при использовании `Mirror` Вы не получите информацию о вложенных классах, потому что данный класс работает только с конкретными экземплярами. Не поможет даже такой вызов:

```
let mirrorValue = Mirror(reflecting: MySwiftClass.self)
```

Если Вы унаследуете рассматриваемый Вами класс от `NSObject`, то Вы всё-равно не увидите вложенные классы, потому что они не поддерживаются языком Objective-C.

Comment: Схожий ответ получил на англ. SO. На данный момент задача решена другим способом. Спасибо!